# Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR. Cannot find module './ZeParser'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, karma-runner

```
 npm WARN unmet dependency C:\MyWebProject\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\active-x-obfuscator requires zeparser@'0.0.5' but will load
 npm WARN unmet dependency C:\MyWebProject\node_modules\zeparser,
 npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.0.7
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
EXEC : >> error : Cannot find module './ZeParser'
EXEC : warning : Task "karma:unit" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

i am trying to install `npm install zeparser` but still i am getting the above warning.

Kindly help.